# Grant aws iam role permissions to an iam user in same account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an AWS role with s3 Read only permissions. I have already configured aws cli for an AWS user. So I want to use the same user to browse s3 files in aws cli. 
what I did is, 
Added trust relationship for root user to the role `arn:aws:iam::<1234...>:role/test-role` so that i can get this to all my iam users

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<1234..>:root",
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

then, I added a policy to user to assume above role.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt12345",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<1234...>:role/test-role"
        }
    ]
}
```

When i try to list , I get permission denied error.

```
aws s3 ls

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
```

I made sure that role has full s3 read permission as follows.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone please guide where the problem is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the CLI you need a profile with the correct credentials.

You should have your credentials in an .aws/credentials file, e.g.:

```
[myprofile]
aws_access_key_id =  ... access key ...
aws_secret_access_key = ... secret access key …
```

Then you can add a profile for the assumed role to the .aws/config file, e.g.:

```
[profile test-role]
source_profile=myprofile
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::<1234...>:role/test-role
```

Finally you set AWS_PROFILE to `test-role` before running the CLI command

```
SET AWS_PROFILE=test-role
aws s3 ls
```

I would have just posted a [link to the AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html) but this site disapproves of link-only answers.

Comment: It works. but i tried to remove all AssumeRole root user and removed assume role which attached, it still works by calling profile. Now the user is not having any policy attached and the role is just having following trust relation but how come it still works ?
```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<1234..>:root",
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @logan, maybe the assumed role credentials are being cached: see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html#cli-configure-role-cache

Comment: you really rock